# If a lens has a 4% Barrel Distortion, what does that mean for images?

Tags: lens, optics, distortion

I know what barrel distortion is, but how do I take a 4% rating and relate that to an image?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We desire a faithful image. We image a rectangle with the same aspect ratio as our camera’s senor/film frame. If we image at unity (life-size) we expect the image of the rectangle to kiss-off at the corners of the image area. With barrel distortion the image will under spill. With pincushion distortion, the image will over spill. The delta  (valuable increment) is expressed as a percentage of the height of the frame.  4% is scarcely noticeable. [image]

Comment: One reviewer of the lens I'm looking at said there was significant barrel distortion; so they must have had some requirement for no distortion.  Your right 4% isn't that much.  But I'll look at that when I try the lens in the store. Thanks.

Comment: what happens when you reach 100% distortion? rotated image?